# pushing an object to an array in state React ERROR(objects are not valid...)

Tags: reactjs

**Im new to react,how can i add an object to an array in a state properly, I am receiving an error :"Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {product}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead." What can i do is to push the object into list every time i click the button?**

```
import React, { useContext, useState } from 'react'
import {SnacksContext} from './Snacks'
import AddtoCart from './AddToCart'
const SnackItem=()=>{
    const [snacks,setSnack]=useContext(SnacksContext)
    const [list,setList]=useState([])
    return(
        <div style={{display:"grid",gridTemplateColumns:"repeat(auto-fit,minmax(200px,1fr))"}}>
            {snacks.map(i=>(
                <div>
                     <img src={i.picture}></img>
                      <h1>{i.product}</h1>
                      <h2>{i.price}</h2>
                      <button onClick={()=>setList(list=>[...list,i])}>buy</button>
                  </div>
            ))}

        </div>
    )
```

Comment: Can you add the value inside ```snacks``` array?

Answer (score -1):

```js
Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {product}).
```

With the error, it is clear that `snacks` is an array of objects in which `product` is a key which is an object. You are trying to render an object - like this - `<h1>{i.product}</h1>`.

So see the property of `i.product` and render it accordingly. Eg: `i.product.title`

```js
                  <div>
                     <img src={i.picture}></img>
                      <h1>{i.product.title}</h1> //<---- see here
                      <h2>{i.price}</h2>
                      <button onClick={()=>setList(list=>[...list,i])}>buy</button>
                  </div>
```